# Radiobutton Tree Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, radio-button

I am developing a search form which displays a number of categories and sub-categories. The client has requested that I do not use cascading dropdowns but to display radiobuttons instead so that the user can see the top level categories at a glance.

I had a bit of a look around for any javascript plugins that might give me a head start and save me from having to write all of the code from scratch but didnt come up with too much.

Can anyone suggest a good plugin that will allow me to display a radio button list in a hierarchical collapsible tree structure?

Cheers,
Tristan

**Solution**
I ended up using this plugin and adapting it to my own needs -> http://code.google.com/p/checkboxtree/

Answer (score 2):

There is a great jQuery plugin called jsTree.

http://www.jstree.com/

I personalize it for my needs as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like a very useful plugin and I will use it in the future. I have already found a plugin that I have customised and used for my current project - http://code.google.com/p/checkboxtree/